# NoSuchMethodException and NoClassDefFoundError in grpc protobuf java

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc, noclassdeffounderror, nosuchmethoderror

I have a gRPC service that I launch, all good no errors. However, when I try to use `grpcui` (`./grpcui -plaintext localhost:9900`) that will read and to the service, I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "grpc-default-executor-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FileDescriptor.internalBuildGeneratedFileFrom([Ljava/lang/String;[Lcom/google/protobuf/Descriptors$FileDescriptor;)Lcom/google/protobuf/Descriptors$FileDescriptor;
    at io.grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflectionProto.<clinit>(ServerReflectionProto.java:103)
    at io.grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflectionGrpc$ServerReflectionBaseDescriptorSupplier.getFileDescriptor(ServerReflectionGrpc.java:234)
    at io.grpc.protobuf.services.ProtoReflectionService$FileDescriptorIndex.<init>(ProtoReflectionService.java:418)
    at io.grpc.protobuf.services.ProtoReflectionService$ServerReflectionIndex.<init>(ProtoReflectionService.java:339)
    at io.grpc.protobuf.services.ProtoReflectionService.updateIndexIfNecessary(ProtoReflectionService.java:97)
    at io.grpc.protobuf.services.ProtoReflectionService.serverReflectionInfo(ProtoReflectionService.java:136)
    at io.grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflectionGrpc$MethodHandlers.invoke(ServerReflectionGrpc.java:220)
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$StreamingServerCallHandler.startCall(ServerCalls.java:224)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl.startWrappedCall(ServerImpl.java:648)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl.startCall(ServerImpl.java:626)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl.access$1900(ServerImpl.java:417)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl$1StreamCreated.runInternal(ServerImpl.java:556)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl$1StreamCreated.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:531)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

and

```
Exception in thread "grpc-default-executor-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflectionProto
    at io.grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflectionGrpc$ServerReflectionBaseDescriptorSupplier.getFileDescriptor(ServerReflectionGrpc.java:234)
    at io.grpc.protobuf.services.ProtoReflectionService$FileDescriptorIndex.<init>(ProtoReflectionService.java:418)
    at io.grpc.protobuf.services.ProtoReflectionService$ServerReflectionIndex.<init>(ProtoReflectionService.java:339)
    at io.grpc.protobuf.services.ProtoReflectionService.updateIndexIfNecessary(ProtoReflectionService.java:97)
    at io.grpc.protobuf.services.ProtoReflectionService.serverReflectionInfo(ProtoReflectionService.java:136)
    at io.grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflectionGrpc$MethodHandlers.invoke(ServerReflectionGrpc.java:220)
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$StreamingServerCallHandler.startCall(ServerCalls.java:224)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl.startWrappedCall(ServerImpl.java:648)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl.startCall(ServerImpl.java:626)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl.access$1900(ServerImpl.java:417)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl$1StreamCreated.runInternal(ServerImpl.java:556)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl$1StreamCreated.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:531)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My service:

```
public class OneSideInitiated extends SideGrpc.SideImplBase {

    @Override
    public void requestStart(RemoteStartRequest request,
                                        StreamObserver<RemoteStartResponse> responseObserver) {

        RemoteStartResponse response = RemoteStartResponse.newBuilder().build();

        responseObserver.onNext(response);
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }
}
```

The class that launches the service:

```
import io.grpc.Server;
import io.grpc.ServerBuilder;
import io.grpc.protobuf.services.ProtoReflectionService;

public class StuffServer {

    private Server server;

    public StuffServer(int port) {

        this.server = ServerBuilder.forPort(port)
                .addService(ProtoReflectionService.newInstance())
                .addService(new OneSideInitiated())
                .build();
    }

    public void start() throws IOException {
        server.start();
    }

    public void stop() throws InterruptedException {...}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CccpServer cccpServer = new StuffServer(9900);
        cccpServer.start();
        cccpServer.blockUntilShutdown();
    }

    private void blockUntilShutdown() throws InterruptedException {...}
}
```

My Maven dependencies are:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>1.26.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.26.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
            <version>1.26.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-services</artifactId>
            <version>1.26.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>23.6.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>proto-google-common-protos</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-testing</artifactId>
            <version>1.26.0</version>
            <scope>testing</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Have tried different combinations of `guava` and `io.grpc` versions, didn't make any difference.
Anyone got any ideas on this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That particular FileDescriptor.internalBuildGeneratedFileFrom() method was added to Protobuf in v3.8. Generally `NoSuchMethodError` errors are caused dependencies being downgraded, commonly by Maven.

You can run `mvn dependency:tree` to check what versions of dependencies are being used. In this case you will find that `com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:0.1.9` is depending on `com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.2.0` and that is the version Maven is using.

The gRPC team recommends always using Maven Enforcer's `requireUpperBoundDeps` to detect when Maven is poorly choosing versions. You can add to your pom.xml:

```
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireUpperBoundDeps/>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

When it detects a failure during build, it provides the versions being depended on elsewhere. Choose the largest version and add it as an explicit dependency to your project:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
      <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I'll also note that proto-google-common-protos:0.1.9 is very old. I'd recommend updating to a more recent version, like 1.17.0. Although you'd have still have experienced this problem with 1.17.0.

Comment: Very informative and exhaustive answer, thank you Sir! You pinpointed the problem; I was using a much older version of grpc to generate the java files.

Comment: gRPC supports old generated code. So if you use an old protoc-gen-grpc-java executable things should still function.