# IncompatibleClassChangeError: class com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$OneofDescriptor Protobuf

Tags: clojure, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java, clojure-java-interop

I have been getting

```
at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7114)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6789)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7094)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6789)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6745)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$HostExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:986)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7106)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6789)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7094)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6789)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6745)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$HostExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:986)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7106)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6789)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7094)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6789)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6745)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$HostExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:986)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7106)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6789)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7094)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6789)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6745)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$HostExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:986)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7106)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6789)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7094)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6789)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7094)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6789)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6745)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6120)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod.parse(Compiler.java:5467)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr.parse(Compiler.java:4029)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7104)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6789)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7094)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6789)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.access$300(Compiler.java:38)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$DefExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:596)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7106)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6789)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6745)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7180)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7635)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:381)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:372)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:463)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:428)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__6824.invoke(core.clj:6126)
    at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:6125)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:6109)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5908)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5903)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__6765.invoke(core.clj:5948)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5947)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5928)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:667)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:5985)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5969)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:667)
    at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:6007)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:6007)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436)
    at nearby_driver_service.octopus_test$eval422$loading__6706__auto____423.invoke(octopus_test.clj:1)
    at nearby_driver_service.octopus_test$eval422.invokeStatic(octopus_test.clj:1)
    at nearby_driver_service.octopus_test$eval422.invoke(octopus_test.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7176)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7165)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7635)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:381)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:372)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:463)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:428)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__6824.invoke(core.clj:6126)
    at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:6125)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:6109)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5908)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5903)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__6765.invoke(core.clj:5948)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5947)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5928)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:667)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:5985)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5969)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:667)
    at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:6007)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:6007)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:665)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:660)
    at user$eval224.invokeStatic(form-init3326873477142158964.clj:1)
    at user$eval224.invoke(form-init3326873477142158964.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7176)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7166)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7635)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7573)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:452)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:454)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:454)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invokeStatic(main.clj:485)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:519)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:516)
    at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:598)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:561)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:705)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$OneofDescriptor has interface com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$GenericDescriptor as super class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2917)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.getMethods(Reflector.java:498)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$HostExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:994)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:7106)
    ... 113 more
```

exception when I am trying to add `[com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java "3.21.2"]`
as dependency in my clojure code.
Reason being I was using older version of protobuf (<3.8) & I faced this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59880287/nosuchmethodexception-and-noclassdeffounderror-in-grpc-protobuf-java)
I fixed it using the solution but now I have started getting IncompativleClassChangeError.
I understand & have some instinct that this is related to some dependency code but somehow am not able to figure out which changes in dependency could avoid this.
currently my project.clj looks like:

```
  [io.grpc/grpc-netty "1.45.1"]
  [io.grpc/grpc-netty-shaded "1.45.1"]
  [io.grpc/grpc-protobuf "1.45.1"]
  [io.grpc/grpc-stub "1.45.1"]
  [com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java "3.21.2"]
```

client.clj

```
;;; client
(def client (clojuregrpcexample.grpc.HelloGrpc/newBlockingStub
               (-> (io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder/forAddress "localhost" (int 35000))
                   (.usePlaintext true)
                   .build)))
    

(defn say-hello [name]
  (println 
   (.getGreeting
    (.sayHello client (-> (clojuregrpcexample.grpc.GrpcExample$Person/newBuilder)
                                   (.setName name)
                                   .build)))))
```

Any hints to remove this issue would be helpful!

Edit

- updated the complete stack trace
- Adding sample code for grpc client call

Comment: When seeking help, please include the full error message you received, including the stacktrace, and the minimal code necessary to reproduce it. Here, that probably means your `ns` clause.

Comment: Anyway, the cause is almost certainly a version mismatch between the protobuf library you explicitly ask for and the version expected by the version of the GRPC library you're using. If you upgraded one, make sure to upgrade the other to a matching version.

Comment: `[io.grpc/grpc-protobuf "1.45.1"]` seems to have been compiled using `[com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java "3.19.2"]`

Comment: @amalloy - updated the  question with stack trace and sample code.

Comment: @dorab thanks, using the mentioned versions helped.